# Is it possible to use androidx-navigation with onClick-databinding without writing boilercode in Fragment?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-databinding, android-architecture-navigation

I want to implement an [androidx-navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/) by using databinding instead of implementing `onClick` handler in code

I have a List-fragment with a livedata element `selectedItemId` and want to open a correspondeng detail-fragment when pressing the edit button. Is something similar to this possible

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <!-- assuming that com.example.MyGeneratedNavigation was 
             generated from .../res/navigation/my_navigation.xml -->
        <variable name="myNavigation" type"com.example.MyGeneratedNavigation" />
        <variable name="selectedItemId" type"..." />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout ...>
        <Button android:id="@+id/edit" 
           android:onClick="@{() -> myNavigation.onShowDetails(selectedItemId)}" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Is this possible without implementing a onClick-handler in the List-fragment ?

**[Update after @ABr answer]**

The proposed solution does not trigger the button event. For further investigations i created my own static function to debug if it gets called

```
<layout ...>
<data>
    <import type="de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo.R" />
    <import type="de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo.GalleryFragment" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout ...>

    <Button ...
        android:onClick="@{view -> GalleryFragment.myNavigate(view,
                                R.id.action_gallery_to_editProperties)}"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

---

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = "GalleryFragment";

public static void myNavigate(Object view, @IdRes int id) {
    // this gets never called neither with `Object view` nor with `View view`
    Log.d (TAG, "myNavigate clicked");
    //  Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(id);
}

}
```

Unfortulately the statement `Log.d` is never called.

If i rename the static method `myNavigate` in the java code and not in layout i get as expected a compile error so databinding is syntactically ok.

---

i use this nav graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
app:startDestination="@id/galleryFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/galleryFragment"
    android:name="de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo.GalleryFragment"
    android:label="fragment_gallery"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_gallery_to_editProperties"
        app:destination="@id/editPropertiesFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/editPropertiesFragment"
    android:name="de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo.EditPropertiesFragment"
    android:label="fragment_edit_properties"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_properties" />
</navigation>
```

and these build.gradle

global build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding.enabled=true

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Theres no need in creating a function inside fragment if you don't need to pass an argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course you can. Firstly you should create a connection in the navgraph to which direction you are planning to move.Then you can use the below imports and onclick.

Please note I am not sure if you can pass parameters inside this method!!!!!

```
<layout>
    <data>
    <import type="com.rf.comm.R"/>
        <import type="androidx.navigation.Navigation"/>
        <!-- assuming that com.example.MyGeneratedNavigation was 
             generated from .../res/navigation/my_navigation.xml -->
        <variable name="myNavigation" type"com.example.MyGeneratedNavigation" />
        <variable name="selectedItemId" type"..." />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout ...>
        <Button android:id="@+id/edit" 
                        android:onClick="@{view -> Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.createServiceFragment)}" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: After asking [Howto androidx-databinding for onClick to static method with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074061/howto-androidx-databinding-for-onclick-to-static-method-with-parameter/56074656#56074656) : My issue was that i also have to replace in fragment: `inflater.inflate(...)` with `DatabindingUtil.inflate(inflater, ....)' and in activity: `setContentView(...)` with `DatabindingUtil.setContentView(this, ...) `. now all is working even with parameter. Thanks a lot

Comment: I just created a bug ticket for "Android Public Tracker     App Development     Android Studio     Design Tools     Navigation Editor" which generated the fragment that did not use `DatabindingUtil`

Comment: Did you manage to send it from the layout itself(along with the argument)

Comment: yes: clicking on edit-butoon called static method with parameters view and int-resourse-id as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074061/howto-androidx-databinding-for-onclick-to-static-method-with-parameter/56074656#56074656

Comment: Yeah that's possible. But what i mentioned was to do these things purely in the layout