# Howto androidx-databinding for onClick to static method with parameter

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-databinding, androidx

(Note: this is a follow up question to [Is it possible to use androidx-navigation with onClick-databinding without writing boilercode in Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055891/)

I want to use androidx-databinding to handle `onClick` calling a static method with parameters 
`Utils.myNavigate(...)` via the xml-layout-file

My Code below is verifyed by the compile process 
**but is never called when i click on the button.**

How to fix this?

My **Layoutfile:**

```
<layout ...>
<data>
    <import type="de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo.R" />
    <import type="de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo.Utils" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout ...>

    <Button ...
        android:onClick="@{view -> Utils.myNavigate(view,
                                R.id.action_gallery_to_editProperties)}"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

My **Static Method implementation:**

```
public class Utils {

public static final String TAG = "Utils";

public static void myNavigate(View view, @IdRes int id) {
    // this gets never called neither with `Object view` nor with `View view`
    Log.d (TAG, "myNavigate clicked");
    //  Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(id);
}

}
```

global **project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}
```

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.k3b.androidx.navigationdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding.enabled=true

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have forgot to bind the layout with the activity.

Change

```java
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
```

To

```java
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_layout_file);
```

If that's not the issue, you may check the [working sample](https://github.com/theapache64/databinding-static-method-test) I created on calling static method using data binding.

Comment: After changing (in AppCompatActiviy:) `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_layout_file);` and (in Fragment) `View view = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout...., container, false).getRoot()` it works as expected. thanks a lot.

Comment: I just created a bug ticket for "Android Public Tracker     App Development     Android Studio     Design Tools     Navigation Editor" which generated the fragment that did not use `DatabindingUtil`